# CodedUI Test SendKey triggers CA1303 for Input Code

Tags: c#, code-analysis, coded-ui-tests

When calling SendKeys with the code for the key (for example `"{ENTER}"`), Code Analysis triggers the following error:

> CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters

The MS class library manual itself shows passing the literal in the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Is there a good solution for this other than suppressing the CA?

Answer (score 0):

I use a managed class for `keycode` literals

```
public static class KeyCode
{
   public static string Return { get { return "{ENTER}"; } }
   public static string Backspace { get { return "{BACKSPACE}"; } }
   public static string F1 { get { return "{F1}"; } }
   public static string PageDown { get { return "{PGDN}"; } }
   ...
   ..
   .
}
```